# AWS Lambda needs to be moved in different Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, rds, amazon-rds, amazon-lambda

I have a Lambda function that is in VPC-A and Subnet 1A and 2A. I want to move it to Subnet 1b and 2B.

The command below is giving error:

```
aws rds modify-db-subnet-group --db-subnet-group-name "XXXX" --subnet-ids "XXX" "YYY" "ZZZ"
```

The error is:

```
Some of the subnets to be deleted are currently in use: subnet-ABCD, subnet-WXYZ (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: d636a255-9cfe-4f1c-89de-77ebcb1b9af3)
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault.  Sadly, without more details, it's impossible to give you a useful answer.  See this link for the information needed: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about *Lambda* but the command that you posted is for modifying *RDS Subnet Group*. These are two completely different things.

If you want to change Lambda subnet use:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --vpc-config ...
```

Hope that helps :)